# Working on a class shared between main program and a function

Tags: function, class, parameter-passing

Apologies if my question seems trivial. I just got back into OOP after a 15 year absence and I'm migrating from Java to python. I have trawled widely for a clear answer but none found. Pls redirect me if answer already exists.

I am looking for best practice advice on what I would call global versus local class handling. The main program of the actual application I am developing would seem to require around 4 major classes (such as the class Register in the attached mock up) and the principle class that builds up a system network will only ever have one instance. Each major class will have various attributes including nested classes such as Person and these nested classes will only ever be used as such ie never called up for use as stand alone instances.

In the example, I call up newReg (my 'main' class) as an instance of Register. 
'Using the option 1' sequence, I call up 2 functions to input and output content of the dynamic array people. I don't pass newReg as a parameter to the functions because it is the only Register class I plan to instantiate. In effect, I use the functions as GOSUB...RETURN routines (if any of you ever used BASIC) in an attempt to unclutter the main program (the draft methods in my real application so far have many loops and checks and nested menu calls and I want to keep these as blocks separate from the main program logic flow). However, this doesn't seem very OOP but since I only need the functions as GOSUB...RETURNs in the main program, it seems a pragmatic approach. But is it good practice?

The alternative option 2 sequence does pass newReg as a parameter to the functions and, with suitably modified functions, I get the same result. This does seem more OOP but I don't see the advantage of doing this if there is only ever going to be one instance of Register called newReg. In fact, if newReg became very big, there may be speed overhead for the program in passing, recreating, passing back and destroying the temporary class parameter in the function. Is this speed overhead worry not an issue?

I could be even more OOP in the case of more complicated classes and only pass those parameters of the class to the method that need processing. I started with this approach but the coding soon became messy and added extra code to the main program flow (extracting data from class and inserting the returned data from the function back into the class) which I want to keep lean and legible.

Should I avoid my preferred option 1 approach and go with option 2? I tried Option 3 approach but it seems to create more complex coding. Advice appreciated.

```
class Register:
    def __init__(self,dd,mm,yy):
        self.d = dd
        self.m = mm
        self.y = yy
        self.people = []

class Person:
    def __init__(self,name,ident):
        self.name = name
        self.ident = ident

def inputPeople():
    name =""
    print("enter 'end' as name to finish update")
    while name != "end":
        name = input("enter name:")
        ID = input ("enter ID:")
        if name == "end":
            return
        newperson = Person(name,ID)
        newReg.people.append(newperson)

def outputRegister():
    print("register date: %s/%s/%s" % (newReg.d, newReg.m, newReg.y))
    for element in newReg.people:
        values = vars(element).values()
        print('|'.join("%10s" % item for item in values))
    return

#main prog option 1: treat newReg globally when calling functions
newReg = Register(12,5,17)
choice =""
while choice != "E":
    choice = input("enter U to update, L to list, E to exit")
    if choice == "U":
        inputPeople()
    if choice == "L":
        outputRegister()
print("session over")

#main prog option 2: pass newReg as a parameter to the functions
newReg = Register(12,5,17)
choice =""
while choice != "E":
    choice = input("enter U to update, L to list, E to exit")
    if choice == "U":
        newReg = inputPeople(newReg) # and modify fn codes accordingly
    if choice == "L":         # to handle newReg as a parameter
        outputRegister(newReg)# rather than a class object in 
print("session over")         # the main body
```

Comment: Might want to try asking on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both options work it is a matter of style and opinion, but my personal opinion that 1 is ok for small scripts, but an improved 2 is the way to go for bigger applications.

Your function inputPeople() in both options is pretty much constrained to operating on an instance that has a people field which has an append interface.  This is not ideal.  With OOP it would be better to have the object you pass in have an interface for adding people, like addPerson(Person).

This will mean that your inputPeople function doesn't need to know data structure is used by the registry to store people.  Also it makes it easier to reuse the function and pass in other types of containers of people as long as the container has a addPerson(Person) method.

With option 1 your inputPeople function can only be used for newreg and not for other things that also may have people.

Comment: Hi Alwyn - your comment gave me inspiration. I gave the function in the actual application that I wrote a second look and I think it can be rewritten as 3 sub functions (with parameter passing) each of which can be reused elsewhere in future. I am happier with this revised approach. Thanks for your time and sharing your thoughts. It helped!

Comment: Thanks Gary.  I started studying OOP when it was still a hack onto Turbo Pascal 5 and for a long time I understood the structure and feature set of OOP, but I missed the important part of OOP which is how do you use this functionality to accomplish goals that go beyond the obvious.  Then I read Bert Bates's Head First Design Patterns and though the patterns are neat, what really struck me was how you use OOP's attributes to achieve the goals of clear code and keeping your code maintainable and easy to reuse and extend at the same time.  Your goals define your code and how you apply tools